# Where Gradle plugins are?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a `build.gradle` file with a bunch of different plugins...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"
apply plugin: 'de.mobilej.unmock'
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
```

but I can't find where there are all defined (classes etc.). Where do I find them locally?

Comment: Similar question with answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811347/2949966

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `$HOME/.gradle/caches/5.4.1/scripts-remapped/` for the classes (at least found one plugin in there; directory `scripts` is for the `buildscript`) and `$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` for the downloaded JAR plugin files, but also downloaded AAR libraries.

[Gradle's user home directory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home) is in every cases where one can find (most of) them.

Comment: The name of the folder is the same as the plugin? Because I can't find some of them

Comment: @Lore the version number and trailing numbers might vary... just search the `files` directory for `*.jar` (which is a little faster then browsing through all those directories with random names).

Comment: The problem is that with this method I can't find all of them

Comment: @Lore which ones in particular? eg. `maven-publish` might even be kind of a framework plugin, which is not being downloaded. You could still download them directly from the repository.

Comment: @Lore you should find whatever is being downloaded in there - and this question lacks any valid reason why you would even need these files, therefore I'd rather suspect an X/Y problem. Fetching from repository is still the most simple, without having to traverse any directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Gradle file structure

```
   ├── caches // (1)
│   ├── 4.8 // (2)
│   ├── 4.9 // (2)
│   ├── ⋮
│   ├── jars-3 // (3)
│   └── modules-2 // (3)
├── daemon // (4)
│   ├── ⋮
│   ├── 4.8
│   └── 4.9
├── init.d // (5)
│   └── my-setup.gradle
├── wrapper
│   └── dists // (6)
│       ├── ⋮
│       ├── gradle-4.8-bin
│       ├── gradle-4.9-all
│       └── gradle-4.9-bin
└── gradle.properties // (7)
```

Your all the applied plugin will be located inside .gradle/version/modules folder

Global cache directory (for everything that’s not project-specific)

Version-specific caches (e.g. to support incremental builds)

Shared caches (e.g. for artifacts of dependencies)

You can checkout this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html) for more information

Comment: Tried to verify that, but you've copied the wrong one directory structure there.